# NoReverseMatch error after upgrade Django version

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm newbie in Django and i read many topic here and not found solution for my case. I believe it's easy, but i can't find the solution.

Basically i have the code in my urls.py and the works fine in Django 1.8.4:

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^leds/', include('ledscontrol.urls')),
    url(r'^', 'controli2c.view.view_home'),
    ]
```

My template file contains

```
        {% url 'controli2c.views.view_home' as home_url%}
        <a href="{% url 'controli2c.views.view_home' %}" {% if request.path == home_url  %} class="active"{% endif %} >HOME</a>
```

When i update Django, i get the error "TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()". Then, i change my urls.py code to:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^leds/', include('ledscontrol.urls')),
url(r'^', 'views.view_home'),
]
```

Now, i have the NoReverseMatch when i open the browser (http://localhost:8000):

"Reverse for 'controli2c.view.view_home' not found. 'controli2c.views.view_home' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

In a post in the forum i found:

"The solution is to update your urls.py to include the view callable. This means that you have to import the view in your urls.py. **If your URL patterns don't have names, then now is a good time to add one, because reversing with the dotted python path no longer works**."

I believe that's my problem. But i don't know what changes i have to do.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Which bit of that don't you understand? You need to use a callable instead of a string, and you need to give it a specific name.

Comment: It looks like you are using [this project](https://github.com/blobsmith/controli2c). It hasn't been updated for 18 months, so it might be better to look for another library. If you do decide to use it, then I would stick with Django 1.8.X (the latest point release is 1.8.18) rather than trying to upgrade it, especially if you are new to Django. Django 1.8 is an LTS, so will be supported until at least April 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

To keep my template file with the same code, i have make these change

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^leds/', include('ledscontrol.urls')),
url(r'^', 'views.view_home',name='controli2c.views.view_home'),
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to pass a callable, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^leds/', include('ledscontrol.urls')),
    url(r'^', views.view_home),
]
```

I think it might work now.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, i write exactly this code in my attempt. So, this is not solution. Thanks!